# Polynomial in $x$ problem

Tags: combinatorics

please help me solve this problem: a polynomial in $x$ is defined by

$$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x ^ 2 + ... + a_{2n} \, x^{2n}  = (x + 2x^2 + ... + nx^n) ^ 2 .$$

Show that: 
$$\sum_{n + 1}^{2n}a_i = n(n + 1)(5n^2 + 5n + 2)/24 .$$

Help please!

Comment: Note: I cleaned up some formatting issues, but the question still needs editing.  The title and first sentence both reference a variable $z$ which does not appear.  I suppose that you meant $x$ instead, but I didn't want to make that change.  Also, did you mean for the $n$ in the sum to be the same as in the degree?

Comment: I think he means the function maps to the integers, when he refers to 'z'.

Comment: @Cataline But, if the relation is true, then it is true algebraically...wouldn't matter if it was $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$ or...

Comment: @lulu True. It's probably just a mistake, typing z instead of x.

Comment: sorry ! i meant x by typing z:/

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a few hints as to how you'd brute force solve this problem (there may be a smarter way to solve it):

For any given $i$, we have $$ a_i = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^i j(i - j) = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^i ji - j^2. $$

Use the formulae $\sum_{k = 1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{k = 1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6}$ to find a closed form for $a_i$.  Then each $a_i$ is a polynomial in $i$, and you can use these formulae plus $\sum_{k = 1}^n k^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ to find the desired sum.